# Stata: Comparing string variables

Tags: stata

I have two string variables that differ on one character for each observation. I need to get the position of that different character.
I have tried to use `indexnot()` function but it yields false results as the characters in both strings are the same.
Here is an illustrative example, and variable `position` is the one I am trying to get to:

```
+--------------+--------------+-----------+
|   String 1   |   String 2   | Position  |
+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| 000002002000 | 000000002000 |         6 |
| 000002102000 | 000002002000 |         7 |
| 000002112000 | 000002102000 |         8 |
| 000002112020 | 000002112000 |        11 |
| 000002112120 | 000002112020 |        10 |
+--------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gen Position = . 

quietly forval j = 1/12 { 
    replace Position = `j' if substr(String1, `j', 1) != substr(String2, `j', 1) & missing(Position)
}
```

Commentary is perhaps redundant here, but will harm no-one.

In the absence of a built-in function to do this, you need to write some code using existing commands and functions. Initialise a `Position` to missing (zero would do fine as an alternative). Then loop over the characters, here 1 to 12 because the example shows 12 character strings. We record the position of the first difference in characters. Note how the condition `missing(Position)` (`Position == .` if you like) restricts changes to the first difference met.

Stata loops automatically over all the observations here, so the only loop needed is over string positions.